# AJAX post request error 404

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to do a AJAX post from index.html in the root to my controller. But it is returning 404 Not Found in the firefox console.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "api/postData",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.debug(result);
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, p3, p4) {
                    console.debug(xhr);
                    var err = "Error " + " " + status + " " + p3;
                    if (xhr.responseText && xhr.responseText[0] == "{")
                        err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message;
                    alert(err);
                }
            });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My Controller:

```
    namespace MyAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/postData")]
    public class MyAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public bool Post()
        {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Do I need to set something in the RouteConfig.cs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your AJAX url to include the method:

```
 url: "api/postData/Post"
```

You could also try changing:

```
 type: "POST"
```

to

```
 method: "POST"
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not correct. The url that you have specified leads to the controller itself. And, as you don't have a default `index` (GET) method you have to specify a route for the method itself:

```
namespace MyAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api")]
    public class MyAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("postData")]
        public bool Post()
        {

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

this will make your desired url to be the one you are currently using.

Ither option is to remove both of the routes. Then your url will be `myapi/post`.

Check the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing#attribute-routing) for more information and options.

Comment: I changed my controller to the way you said, but it still returning 404 not found

Comment: Hm this is quite strange. Can you try and change the method type to Action or Action result (instead of bool). There is something small here, that I can't see. Also - check the network tab of the browser. What is the url that the request is trying to reach? Is it the same as you are expecting

Comment: Yeah... Very odd. Even if I type the url http://localhost:64049/api/postData it returns HTTP 404. Is it because I'm using ApiController?

Comment: Did you try changing the method type? The ApiController has nothing to do with this

Comment: Yes, I changed to ActionResult and still the same problem

Comment: This is weird. Have you made any changes to the route configuration or so?